# How to set a keybinding to create and jump to the next line in emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I have the following code that attempts to create a new line and then jump to it. The idea is that `move-end-of-line` will jump to the end of the current line, and `["C-m"]` would act as return/enter. Yet executing this command gives the error: "wrong number of arguments". How do I fix this?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'new-line)

(defun new-line ()
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line)
  ["C-m"]
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read the Emacs & elisp manuals: these questions are pretty easy to answer.  Here's one way to do it.

```
(defun insert-line-after-line (&optional n)
  (interactive "p")
  (end-of-line 1)                       ;end of current line
  (open-line n)                         ;open n new lines
  (forward-line 1))                     ;go to start of first of them
```

But seriously: Emacs has very extensive self-documentation, it is easy to find out how to do these things.

Comment: +1 for the advice to consult the manuals. The manual "Intro to Programming in Emacs Lisp" is the place to start -- `C-h i`.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to record a macro and use that.

```
M-x kmacro-start-macro
C-e
C-m
M-x kmacro-end-macro
```

If you don't care about the macro persisting, just run it:

```
C-x e
```

But if you want it to persist you would save it:

```
M-x name-last-kbd-macro  new-line
M-x insert-kbd-macro new-line
```

and paste the output into your initialisation file (with your shortcut definition):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'new-line)
(fset 'new-line
   [end return])
```

Answer (score 0):

`["C-m"]` is like the way you specify a key for doing a key binding, but this is not the same as how you programmatically tell Emacs to insert a character into a document. You could use `(insert-char ?\^M)` (see ref [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Ctl_002dChar-Syntax)), but that would result in a literal ^M character (try it; another way to do the same thing interactively is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>). `(insert "\n")` seems to be what you're looking for.

Also, the reason you're getting the message "wrong number of arguments" is because `(move-end-of-line)` requires an argument when called out of interactive context. `(move-end-of-line 1)` works.

That said, possibly an easier way to achieve the result you're looking for is with the following setting:

`(setq next-line-add-newlines t)`

This will allow you to just do C-n at the end of the file and not worry about the distinction between moving and inserting.